# Meteor.js, Router.go, pass router parameter but url can't show and result is wrong

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new for Meteor.js and javascript. I faced a weird question when I tried to pass router parameter.
My code like:

```
Router.route('/ends/:keyword', function () {
  this.render('navbar', {
    to:"navbar"
  });
  this.render('search_list', {
    to: "search_list",
    data:function(){
      var keywords = this.params.keyword;
      var filtered = Websites.find({ "description": { $regex: keywords }});
      return filtered;   
    }
  });
},{ name: 'search.show' });

Template.search_form.events({
  "submit .js-search-website-form":function(event){
    var keyword = event.target.keywords.value;
    Router.go('search.show',{ keyword:keyword });       
  }
});
```

For example when I submit `course`, I expected the url change to `/ends/course`, but it shows as `/ends/?`.
However if I type `/ends/course` directly in address bar, it works properly. I would be very thankful if someone can give me some clues. I spent the whole day on it, but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Router.go('search.show',{keyword:keyword},{});
```

Comment: Why would that help? You're just specifying null query parameters.

Comment: Kawsar, thank you very much for your reply. But I tested in my computer, it still failed. I doubt the result show, but can't be kept. It flashed quickly and then disappear. And then the website change to "/ends/?". It is very weired.

Comment: I googled the problem and find the reason. I need prevent click submit. So add a line: event.preventDefault(); It works now. Thanks!

Comment: yes, `event.preventDefault()` stops Meteor to reload the page.